# How to use a field without including it in other Table in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a simple data of employees with their ID,Name,Salary and other fields in a table named EMP_DUES. I want to make another table and use a calculated field which is 10% of total salary, without using the salary field in this new table.

But when I try the expression: 
**`EMP_DUES.[GROSS_PAY]*0.1`** for that field, it gives a error saying **"The expression cannot be saved because it refers to another table".**

[The Table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1Ubl.png)

[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mFJL.png)

Comment: Are you sure you want to make another table, or are you looking for a query?

Comment: @UnhandledException : I just need anything but that thing should not include that salary field in its Datasheet view.

Comment: Ok, so lets think about a query. Given the picture you provided, please tell us how the result should look like (maybe also by using a picture additionally).

Comment: @UnhandledException: Added.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for missing information. So finally thats your query:

`Select EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, [GROSS_PAY]*0.1 As [10% OF GROSS_PAY] From EMP_DUES`

To use it, create a new query, switch to SQL view, paste the query, save, name and close it, and finally open it like a table.

Comment: Just one more question, What would be the query if I have also another table named x and a field y in it and I want the field in query to show [BASIC_PAY]-[y]

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow. I would need more details.